# How to get 2nd row from mysqldatabase during run time?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btn_ok_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_ok.Click
    mysqlconn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "select *  from login "
    cmd.Connection = mysqlconn
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()

    If txtuser.Text = "" And txt_password.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter user name and password", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Login form")
    Else
        If txtuser.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please select user name", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Login form")
        Else
            If txt_password.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please enter password", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Login form")
                'If (dr.FieldCount > 0) Then

                'Dim i As Integer = dr(1)
                ' For i = 1 To dr.FieldCount

                'user = dr("user").ToString
                ' password = dr("password").ToString
            ElseIf ((txtuser.Text = '" & txt_username.text & "') And (txt_password.Text = '" & txt_password.text & "')) Then
          form2.Show()


            Else : MsgBox("Password missmatch.", vbCritical, "Invalid password")
            End If
        End If
        End If
    dr.Close()

    cmd.Dispose()

    mysqlconn.Close()
    mysqlconn.Dispose()

End Sub
```

I have one table login.username and password are two columns.I am trying to fetch username and password in application  from the login table in above code but i can not fetch 2nd row entry from login table as i have two rowsrs(1)username=abc,passowrd=abc 2) username=xyz,password=xyz)
How will i get 2nd login entry during runtime?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `DataTable` to hold all your rows or use [`DataReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.datareader.read.aspx) to advance the reader to the next record.

1. `DataTable`

   ```
   Dim tblUsers = New DataTable
   Using con = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(conString)
       Using da = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("select *  from login", con)
           da.Fill(tblUsers)
       End Using
   End Using

   If tblUsers.Rows.Count > 1 Then
       Dim user = tblUsers.Rows(1).Field(Of String)("User")
       Dim password = tblUsers.Rows(1).Field(Of String)("Password")
   End If
   ```
2. DataReader:

   ```
   Using con = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(conString)
       Using cmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("select *  from login", con)
           Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
               If reader.Read Then
                   ' first user '
                   If reader.Read Then
                       ' second user '
                       Dim user = reader.GetString("User")
                       Dim password = reader.GetString("Password")
                   End If
               End If
           End Using
       End Using
   End Using
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to check the couple (username, password), well, search the couple in the table and not in the DataReader. The only assumption here is that the couple (username, password) is unique in the login table.

In this case, use two parameters in the query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = @username AND password = @password"
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", username))
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password))

'then execute and check the results:
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
if dr.Read() then
  'login successful
else
  'login failed
end
```

Comment: if i do dr.read()---application is accepting all values entered in user and password textbox but i want to match with database whether it(username and password,a row) exist then only navigate to other form

Comment: Exactly! If dr.Read() then navigate other form, otherwise the row (username, password) does not exist in the table.